# Screws used for deck - how to replace?

Tags: wood, deck, screws

I bought a house with large raised deck, and the home inspector told me that I need to replace all of the screws with no shear screws, and that since they used screws originally, I cannot use nails now. I've found no-shear screws that look like they were intended for the braces used on the deck. These screws appear to be just slightly thicker, which seems good to ensure a tight fit, but they are not as long as the screws currently in the deck. Will this cause issues or instability? Do I need to use no-shear screws that are both wider and as long or longer than the screws currently in the deck?

Finally, is there any chance that they used appropriate screws originally (pictures included)? How could I determine this?

**Update I've added another image showing where these are located. They are the only connectors for the horizontal supports directly under the deck surface and run from the house to a set of posts on the other side of the deck. The connector on the other side rests on the posts and these are attached to that piece. Thanks for all the comments and suggestions so far!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a picture of these shear strength rated screws and at least a full specification. I would like to look them up. Personally I think it would be irrelevant that the current screws are longer than the new ones

Comment: I'm confused by what I'm seeing. I've never used hangers in a pass-through situation like that. What are they hanging on?

Comment: I agree with isherwood - those hangers look to me as though they're being used incorrectly. You can even see in the last picture where one of the screws has gone in skew and is barely holding on to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you only need to replace the screws that mount the hanger to the ledger. The screws that go diagonally through the joists aren't in shear and should be fine.

I'd think that no-shear screws of the same size (#8?) as the original screws would do, and hanger nails are typically only 1-1/2" long anyway, so that they penetrate the joist that they're hanging from. [Here is Simpson Strong-tie's offering](http://www.fastenersplus.com/9-x-1-1-2-Strong-Tie-SD-Connector-Screw-Galvanized-Class-55-Pkg-10?gclid=Cj0KEQjwrsDIBRDX3JCunOrr_YYBEiQAifH1FmwQRyYCpPbmutznQMLihz8_cqdNvqmR-RRDFRHWd7saArHp8P8HAQ).

Comment: Wouldn't the instructions for the connectors specify the type and size of the screws for a given application?  If the instructions say #9, then you cannot use #8, right? If the instructions say #8, then I don't think you can use #9. What is the problem with using a self drilling #9 in a hole previously occupied by a #8? The use of other than the specified screws is completely unacceptable given collapses of decks have occurred with profoundly tragic loss of life. Before installing them get confirmation from the inspector that the new screws are acceptable.

Comment: Change **all** the screws to the specified screw and confirm beforehand  with the inspector.

Comment: There are no "instructions" with a hanger. The fastener called for depends on the use case. As for the diagonal screws, It's a safe bet that no deck has ever collapsed due to those failing. If there's enough lateral force to pull a joist out of the hanger, the grain of the lumber will tear out before the screws in that photo will fail. Also, Simpson doesn't even supply a screw for that scenario. It would be overkill.

Comment: Of course, I must defer to expert opinion, but USP do recommend LumberLok for the face attachment and why not use them for the diagonal screws too. Especially if as is noted above in the original installation the screws were not angled. If those joist screws are replaced for that reason, would you use nails angled in or LumberLok #9 2-7/8" screws? http://www.uspconnectors.com/pdf/technical/2100_lumberlok.pdf

Comment: What is the purpose of those larger open holes near the top on the joist faces of the hanger?

Comment: Couldn't say, but they aren't intended for fasteners to my knowledge.

Comment: Another comment from an amateur is offered here for correction or even dismissal by experts: Presumably the OP's pictures are not of the joint at the ledger.This joist hanger is shown on the USP website as being used for a joint were the joist butts against the perpendicular member. The screws angling through the end of the joist are supposed to penetrate deeply into the perpendicular member to pull the joist into tight contact. The friction of this contact is a significant part of the load bearing ability of this connector, isn't it? As @isherwood implied this connector is not acceptable here

Comment: No, the friction isn't a factor. In reality, hangers are often used at both ends of the joist, and that friction wouldn't be a reliable consideration at both ends. It's the penetration of the diagonal nails that lends to the load rating.

Comment: The OP asked about retrofitting screws. @isherwood pointed out that the joint in the picture was not a butt joint, but rather a "pass-through", and his concerns were seconded by brhans.  I wish the OP would clarify the location of the joint in the picture and maybe show a picture of a joint of a joist and the ledger, or at least describe those joints.

Comment: I've updated with pictures and description of the location for the braces. Thanks and sorry I don't have the correct vocabulary yet to adequately describe the construction!

Comment: So from the additional picture it appears that the ledger is continuous and the joists butted to it, just what these hangers are designed for. Were the original pictures of joints of blocking in the middle of the joist span? Following up on the comment by @isherwood about friction not being a factor in the load rating, I found that USP allows up to a 1/8" gap with no reduction in load rating. http://www.uspconnectors.com/pdf/technical/tech-bulletin-990-gaptesting.pdf

Comment: OK I admit it, I cannot tell from the added picture if (all) of the joists are butted to the ledger like this http://www.uspconnectors.com/pdf/technical/JUS_2015_9prov_S.pdf. Are all of the joists butted to the ledger? Where is the joint or joints in the first two pictures?

Comment: @JimStewart I think pictures 1 & 2 may be deceiving - I accidentally chose the one place on the deck where the brace is attached to separate pieces of wood on either side. The others attach like in the linked document. So the majority of the braces attach to a continuous ledger.